# How to express size of matrix

Tags: matrices

I am sorry if my question is not smart enough. Via this post ([Is there any standard notation for specifying dimension of a matrix after the matrix symbol?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370545/is-there-any-standard-notation-for-specifying-dimension-of-a-matrix-after-the-ma)), I am still bit confused with matrix notation.

Would you show me how I could express the size of square matrix called J (n x n) with n dependent on cumulative weight fraction?

$\sum_{i=1}^n \omega_i = 1$

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I think, $A_{m,n}$ is quite common and the danger of a misunderstanding is very low.